# How to Recover Ubuntu Home Folder?

Tags: 11.04, mount, home-directory

I had a different partition that serverd as my home folder. Few days ago I had to format my system and I forgot to mount that partition as home folder (/home). Now I have the files but my settings and configurations are not restored as it is not my /home. Is there any way to mount that partition permanently as home or will I have to format again
My details:
Samsung SF411 laptop with Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not installed, install **GPartEd**: open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Now open **GParted** and look for the partition which you used as home folder. Right click on it and copy the UUID and note down the fylesystem type.
Now type in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and add a line in it:

```
UUID=<the_UUID_you_copied> /home <ext4_or_the_partition_tye> defaults 0 2
```

Save and reboot.